# Unread notification from ignored DM in Discord - how to remove?

Tags: notifications, discord

I received a message from a spammer on Discord and clicked ignore without reading it. I now have a little red "1" on the Discord icon denoting one unread message.

[image]

How do I mark it as read and remove this notification? I can't find the ignored message anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your list of blocked users is under the "Friends" tab:

[image: Sidebar: Friends, Nitro. Top bar: Online, All, Pending, Blocked]

However, the notification is probably for Nitro. You can tell that it's not a real notification because the browser tab will not include it in the count. For example, I have the Nitro ad and 1 unread DM and my browser tab says "1".

Just view the Nitro ad to remove the notification.